# Promises with _.each async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

```
var TheMovieDb = require('themoviedb');
var moviedbClient = new TheMovieDb('*****');
var movieJson = require("./seedMovieDB/movieName.json");
var MovieEntry = require('./movie.model');
var movieApi = new TheMovieDb('1b3819c5f61aaef99edf4c47a5de46f4', 'en');
var P = require('bluebird');
var _ = require('underscore');
var moviedb = module.exports = {
indexMovie : function indexMovie(){
            MovieEntry.removeAsync({})
            .then (function() {
                _.each(movieJson, function(val, key, cb){
                            movieApi.searchMovies(val.name).then (function(mDetails) {
                            if(mDetails !== undefined){
                                _.each(mDetails , function(val, key, cb){
                                        var m = new MovieEntry({
                                            id: val.id,
                                            title : val.title,
                                            originalTitle : val.originalTitle,
                                            year : val.year,
                                            popularity : val.popularity,
                                            voteAverage : val.voteAverage,
                                            votes : val.votes,
                                            isAdult : val.isAdult,
                                            video : val.video,
                                            poster : val.poster,
                                            backdrop : val.backdrop,                        
                                        });
                                        m.save(function(err, movie_saved){
                                            if(err){
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }else{
                                                console.log("saved");
                                            }
                                        }); 
                                })
                            }                       
                        }).catch(function(err){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                });
        });
}
```

}

I want to return a promise or something, that will ensure that once all my each calls, that is the asyn searchMovie calls made, are over, and then I can use .then() to retrieve stuff from Database to which I am storing in code. 
I am new to promises and do not know how to do this. 
I have a controller which calls the indexMovie function, once the call is over I would like to retrieve the saved values from the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Promise.each` instead of `_.each` to wait for async actions. If the actions are not related use `Promise.map` instead so they can execute concurrently.

First - the correct solution would be to make your db calls perform queries in batch, rather than query the API 100 times for 100 things, query it once.  `movieApi.searchMovies(val.name)` should have a `movieApi.searchMovies(...arrr)` alternative that works on multiple values and so on.

That said, the main part becomes:

```
return Promise.map(movieJson, x => searchMovies(x.name)).map(x =>
    new MovieEntry(val);
).map(x =>
    x.save()
).then(x =>
    console.log("All Done!")
).catch(e => {
    console.error("Error somewhere", e);
    throw e;
});
```

Comment: You can make use of Promise.All API which is already a standard for these kinda situations. instead of your solution.

Comment: @Nirus: OP is specifically asking for bluebird, there's nothing wrong with this

Answer (score -2):

Just add **promise().done(function(){** at the end of your each

```
var moviedb = module.exports = {
indexMovie : function indexMovie(){
            MovieEntry.removeAsync({})
            .then (function() {
                _.each(movieJson, function(val, key, cb){
                            movieApi.searchMovies(val.name).then (function(mDetails) {
                            if(mDetails !== undefined){
                                _.each(mDetails , function(val, key, cb){
                                        var m = new MovieEntry({
                                            id: val.id,
                                            title : val.title,
                                            originalTitle : val.originalTitle,
                                            year : val.year,
                                            popularity : val.popularity,
                                            voteAverage : val.voteAverage,
                                            votes : val.votes,
                                            isAdult : val.isAdult,
                                            video : val.video,
                                            poster : val.poster,
                                            backdrop : val.backdrop,                        
                                        }).promise().done(function(){
                                             //the stuff you need
                                        });
                                        m.save(function(err, movie_saved){
                                            if(err){
                                                console.log(err);
                                            }else{
                                                console.log("saved");
                                            }
                                        }); 
                                })
                            }                       
                        }).catch(function(err){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: How would I run a piece of code when all the saves complete?